# Kentico - Restrict Related Pages to Localized Pages only

Tags: kentico

I have a multilingual site and use the Related Pages functionality here and there. What I've noticed is that related pages are not localized, meaning if I add a related page for the U.S. site, that page will be related to the U.K. site as well. And that's not what I want.

Is there a way to restrict Related Pages to only pages that are available in the current culture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict relationship per site, but not per culture. you define relationship between tree nodes - not between documents.

You can restrict per site when you create relationship name (this include 2 tables `CMS_RelationshipNameSite` and `CMS_RelationshipName`) and name  will be available when you create relationship between pages. Behind the scenes all sites use `View_CMS_Relationship_Joined`: So if a relation between 2 pages is already defined - it doesn't matter whether this relationship name is enabled for your site or not.

Relationships Module is sealed - so you will not be able to add culture.

That being said you can create your own custom form control and use custom table to define relationship between pages the way you want.  As far as I understand you need `document to document` not `node to node`

Comment: Just to add to what Peter wrote - the related pages module is pretty old and when you check the mentioned DB tables, you will see it is storing the Left and Right NodeID - nodeID is coming from the CMS_Tree table which does not holed culture specific data. For more details please see: https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/custom-development/working-with-pages-in-the-api/page-database-structure